# What is this 8-pin fpc place On RPi 4?

Tags: pi-4, hardware, electronics

I was looking at my Raspberry Pi 4B and I saw something like a not soldered place for fpc connector and I got curious what is that!???

**just Look under USB2 at top right corner in the image bellow.**
[image: just Look under USB2]
[image: just Look under USB2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a JTAG connector used for development and testing. Here's a picture of an old Pi B+ featuring the signal names printed on it:

[image]

AFAIK it's useless unless you have VideoCore documentation and tools from Broadcom.